# Running normal application inside JBoss

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I need to run a normal Java application, without interface or anything, inside JBoss AS 7. The application will have threads started from time to time that will do some jobs, and then disconnect, so the application will be running a timer or something to do it.

So I need an entry point to my application, to start the timer that will start the threads, and I don't know how to do it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You don't require application server for that. Use ExecutorService

Comment: the advantages of using an app server for simple backend jobs include transaction management, shared resource management (e.g. JNDI or if you have an EJB API that is used both by backoffice automation as well as some kind of front end).  So i wouldn't say that your statement always applies, @AmitD.  granted, most of the time, a simple java app will do.  also look into Spring Batch

Comment: as @foampile said, I already have a web application that uses some facilities from JBoss, and that application that I need now will use some modules of that application, so yes, I really need it to run on JBoss :)

Comment: essentially, you want to access the EAR domain from within a regular Java main class.  this might be helpful:  https://community.jboss.org/thread/141688

Comment: Nope, is more like "how to tell JBoss to call the main method of my regular Java class"